# Excel - Formula reference to cell on the same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm trying to build a simple formula: if the cell on the same row as current cell, but column J is either =1 or empty, then the result is 1, else 0.

The part about =1 works, the part about="" does not for some reason.

Here is my formula:

```
    =IF(OR("J"&ROW()=1,"J"&ROW()=""),1,0)
```

Can anyone help me find out why "J"&ROW()="" returns false, even if it is clearly true? The "J"&ROW()=1 returns true if the target cell is 1.

Another thing i tested is "J"&ROW()=j50, where 50 is the actual row number, and this also returned false, which does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need either INDIRECT to turn the string into a cell reference

```
=IF(OR(INDIRECT("J"&ROW())=1,INDIRECT("J"&ROW())=""),1,0)
```

or use INDEX (as INDIRECT is volatile)

```
=IF(OR(INDEX(J:J,ROW())=1,INDEX(J:J,ROW())=""),1,0)
```

Comment: Just to add to this perfect answer, might you opt to choose R1C1 notation it becomes a little easier: `=IF(OR(RC10=1;RC10="");1;0)`

Comment: Thanks @JvdV - yes I never use RC notation but it would make sense here. Add as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case it makes sense to make use of RC notation. A formula would look like this:

`=IF(OR(RC10=1;RC10="");1;0)`